# How to use Azure DevOps version control system (old TFS), using Android Studio?

Tags: android, azure, tfs

Working with Git in Android Studio is very easy.
Working with TFS (now Azure DevOps) in Visual Studio is very easy.

Yet there is this condition that we want to use TFS's custom check-in policies for Android projects. And we're stuck at this point to require developers to install Visual Studio only for that purpose.

Developers work inside Android Studio, but get the latest version and check-in via Visual Studio's Team Explorer.

I searched and I couldn't find another tool to connect to Azure DevOps TFS. Is there another tool out there?

Comment: Do you mean how to connect Android Studio to Azure DevOps with TFVC (not git)?

Comment: yeah, that's correct. I want to know how to connect to Azure DevOps TFS from Android Studio.

Comment: did you try install Azure DevOps plugin? it supports also TFVC

Comment: Microsoft's page says it only supports Azure DevOps's Git VCS.

Comment: did you try? the plugin page says it supports also tfvc.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps Services Plugin for Android Studio supports both Git and TFVC. It enable working with Git and TFVC repositories on Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015+.

Please check your TFS version to see whether it meets the requirement (TFS 2015+), and get more information from the website below:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops